# Pi4J - Changing GPIOs from and to Input, Low and High

Tags: gpio, led, java, pi4j

I am trying to create something which uses Charlieplexing, and to use it, I need to be able to turn GPIO Pins to and from different states (Low, High and Input) from what I understand from this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECXk95qYZu8.

To make a pin low (according to [this](http://pi4j.com/usage.html#Provision_Pins)), I would do:

```
final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
GpioPinDigitalOutput myLed = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_04,PinState.LOW);
```

or then
`myLed.low();` and likewise with High.

The problem is I don't think I can change the Pin's state to "Input". [This](http://pi4j.com/usage.html#Provision_Pins) says that I would have needed to create the variable as an `GpioPinDigitalInput`, not an `GpioPinDigitalOutput`.

Does anyone know how I can change a pin's state from High or Low to Input and vica-versa? Will "re-declaring" the variable work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I used a `GpioPinDigitalMultipurpose`. More info can be found [here](http://pi4j.com/apidocs/com/pi4j/io/gpio/GpioPinDigitalMultipurpose.html).

One can then do:

```
// Provisions the pin.
GpioPinDigitalMultipurpose mypin = gpio.provisionDigitalMultipurposePin(RaspiPin.GPIO_04, PinMode.DIGITAL_INPUT);

// Sets it as an Output pin.
mypin.setMode(PinMode.DIGITAL_OUTPUT);

// Sets the state to "high".
mypin.high();

// Sets the state to "low".
mypin.low();

// Sets it as an Input pin.
mypin.setMode(PinMode.DIGITAL_INPUT);
```

Comment: why not use GpioPinDigitalMultipurpose for every in then? does it have some performance implications?